I can only use 100GB of 2x1TB disks with LVM and a RAID
I have the following disks
lsblk
  lsblk

  lsblk
  NAME                      MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
  loop0                       7:0    0  63,9M  1 loop /snap/core20/2182
  loop1                       7:1    0  63,9M  1 loop /snap/core20/2264
  loop2                       7:2    0    87M  1 loop /snap/lxd/27948
  loop3                       7:3    0    87M  1 loop /snap/lxd/27428
  loop4                       7:4    0  39,1M  1 loop /snap/snapd/21184
  loop5                       7:5    0  38,7M  1 loop /snap/snapd/21465
  sda                         8:0    1   931G  0 disk
  ├─sda1                      8:1    1     1G  0 part /boot/efi
  ├─sda2                      8:2    1     2G  0 part /boot
  └─sda3                      8:3    1 927,9G  0 part
    └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0    0   100G  0 lvm  /
  sr0                        11:0    1  1024M  0 rom

Why does it say I have an LV with only 100GB when the sum of sda1-3 is more than 100GB?
lspci -knn | grep 'RAID bus controller'
01:00.0 RAID bus controller [0104]: Adaptec Series 8 12G SAS/PCIe 3 [9005:028d] (rev 01)

lsscsi
[0:0:0:0]    disk    ASR8405  Raid1 Mirror     V1.0  /dev/sda
[0:1:0:0]    disk    ATA      PNY 1TB SATA SSD 215a  -
[0:1:1:0]    disk    ATA      PNY 1TB SATA SSD 215a  -
[2:0:0:0]    cd/dvd  ASUS     DRW-24D5MT       2.00  /dev/sr0

Hope you can help me I have no clue about this stuff, unfortunately :-(
I tried parted
(parted) print all
Model: ASR8405 Raid1 Mirror (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  1128MB  1127MB  fat32              boot, esp
 2      1128MB  3276MB  2147MB  ext4
 3      3276MB  1000GB  996GB


Model: Linux device-mapper (linear) (dm)
Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv: 107GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags:

Number  Start  End    Size   File system  Flags
 1      0,00B  107GB  107GB  ext4


(parted) resizepart 3 996G
Warning: Shrinking a partition can cause data loss, are you sure you want to continue?
Yes/No? No
(parted)

But in order to not lose data I fear to proceed also because I do not know if this is the problem I'm facing.
OK now I tried
lvdisplay
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv
  LV Name                ubuntu-lv
  VG Name                ubuntu-vg
  LV UUID                1lveHV-7kL0-UcbK-3AoX-Oczm-3l1t-rFVpY3
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time ubuntu-server, 2024-02-12 19:05:57 +0100
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                100,00 GiB
  Current LE             25600
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:0

lvextend -L +996G /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv
  Insufficient free space: 254976 extents needed, but only 211951 available

lvextend -L +211951 /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv
  Rounding size to boundary between physical extents: 206,98 GiB.
  Size of logical volume ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv changed from 100,00 GiB (25600 extents) to 306,98 GiB (78588 extents).
  Logical volume ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv successfully resized.


OK this has worked for me
lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv
  Size of logical volume ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv changed from 306,98 GiB (78588 extents) to 927,93 GiB (237551 extents).
  Logical volume ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv successfully resized.

but df -h hasn't changed at all
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                              6,3G  3,2M  6,3G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv   98G   59G   35G  63% /
tmpfs                               32G     0   32G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5,0M     0  5,0M   0% /run/lock
/dev/sda2                          2,0G  253M  1,6G  14% /boot
/dev/sda1                          1,1G  6,1M  1,1G   1% /boot/efi
tmpfs                              6,3G  4,0K  6,3G   1% /run/user/1000

So I still can not use the Disk space (even after rebooting)

You probably just need to extend the logical volume and filesystem to use the more (or all) of the physical volume - see for example Resize the root partition of Ubuntu 20.04 with an lvm partition

Hi steeldriver I tried it but I'm not sure what happens to the data

@karel partly it helped now and added the remaining GBs but still df finds only ~100 GB :-(

Since you didn't add -r or --resizefs to the successful lvresize command, you will need to run resize2fs separately (step 4 of the linked answer)

@steeldriver you are right now it works - I guess you can mark the question now as a duplicate then. Thank you for helping!

Does this answer your question? Resize the root partition of Ubuntu 20.04 with an lvm partition
